# In angular2 I only want to add the addthis plugin to a specific route e.g. my /blog url but when I add a the script library it doesnt work

Tags: typescript, angular, addthis, add-this-event

In Angular2 I only want to add the **addthis plugin** to a specific route e.g. my **/blog** url but when I add a the script library it doesn't work.

It only seems to work on the `index.html` and not on a specific view like blog.html

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:
I implemented it for my use case following ng-addthis but adding a few extra checks for Angular SSR.

```
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538552/in-angular2-i-only-want-to-add-the-addthis-plugin-to-a-specific-route-e-g-my-b
 * Reinitiate add this.
 */ 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

@Injectable()
export class AddThisService {
    constructor(){}
    private removeScript(){
        let element     = null;
        let divElements = null;
        let divElement  = null;

        element = document.getElementById('addthis-js');
        if (element) {
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }

        divElement = document.getElementById('_atssh');
        if (divElement) {
            divElement.style.display = "none";
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers');
        while (divElements.length > 0) {
            divElements[0].parentNode.removeChild(divElements[0]);
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-desktop');
        while (divElements.length > 0) {
            divElements[0].parentNode.removeChild(divElements[0]);
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-mobile');
        while (divElements.length > 0) {
            divElements[0].parentNode.removeChild(divElements[0]);
        }

        return true;
    }
    showLayers() {
        var divElements = null;
        var divElement  = null;
        console.log('what here..');

        divElement = document.getElementById('_atssh');
        if (divElement) {
            divElement.style.display = "block";
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers');
        for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
            divElements[0].style.display = "block";
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-desktop');
        for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
            divElements[0].style.display = "block";
        }

        divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-mobile');
        for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
            divElements[0].style.display = "block";
        }

        return true;        
    }

    hideLayers () {
            var divElements = null;
            var divElement  = null;

            divElement = document.getElementById('_atssh');
            if (divElement) {
                divElement.style.display = "none";
            }

            divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers');
            for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
                divElements[0].style.display = "none";
            }

            divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-desktop');
            for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
                divElements[0].style.display = "none";
            }

            divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('addthis-smartlayers-mobile');
            for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
                divElements[0].style.display = "none";
            }

        return true;
    }

    private loadProject(key: string, hideLayers:boolean) {
        return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
            switch (true) {                
                case (!document || !window):
                /**
                 * For Angular Universal
                 */
                    observer.error('Cannot render it on Server');
                    observer.complete();
                case ((document.getElementById('addthis-js') != null)):

                    if (hideLayers) {
                        this.hideLayers();
                    } else {
                        this.showLayers();
                    }
                    if ((<any>window).addthis.layers && (<any>window).addthis.layers.refresh) {
                        (<any>window).addthis.layers.refresh();
                    }
                    observer.next(true);
                    observer.complete();
                    break;

                case (!key):
                    observer.error('no-project');
                    observer.complete();
                    break;

                default :
                    var script    = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type   = 'text/javascript';
                    script.id     = 'addthis-js';
                    script.async  = true;
                    script.src    = 'https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=' + key;
                    script.onload = (ev: Event) =>{
                        if (hideLayers) {
                            this.hideLayers();
                        } else {
                            this.showLayers();
                        }
                        (<any>window).addthis.init();
                        observer.next(true);
                        observer.complete();
                    };

                    var first = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    first.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first);
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param accountKey eg. ra-13245612346
     * @param hideLayers eg. true for hiding in a particular state and true for showing in another.
     */
    initAddThis(accountKey:string, hideLayers:boolean):Observable<any> {
        return this.loadProject(accountKey, hideLayers);
    };
}
```

Then inject the service in your providers section of the main module and use it in ngAfterViewInit hook, like below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
    //Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.
    this._addThis.initAddThis('ra-123456asdf', false).subscribe();
}
```

You can also use [isPlatformBrowser](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser) method for checking platform before calling initAddThis method if you are using Angular Universal.

Comment: How to set 
url: "THE URL",
   title: "THE TITLE",
   description: "THE DESCRIPTION",
   media: "THE IMAGE" for addthis

Comment: @MehulMali - You do that inside of your html addthis widget template- 

 <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" [attr.data-url]="data.affiliate_link" data-title="Your Title" data-description="Your description" ></div>

Comment: @Artipixel how does an inline div display? I add it in html but it doesn't display, only expanded widget